# where can i find the location of the sqlite database in android phone?

Tags: sqlite, flash

i'm currently working on android game development in flash cs6 (air for android) and i'm using sqlite to save data's in the game. My main problem is that when i publish the game and copy the apk file in an android phone, it shows that the data is saved but i cannot find the location where it is saved. Where can i possibly see it? I want to locate where it is save even if the phone is not rooted, is it possible? I tried to look for the path but when i'm trying to locate it the phone doesn't obtain that path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DDMS (Dalvik Debug Monitor) located in your sdk_path/tools/ddms. Select the emulator.
1)Go into the menu Device > File Explorer.
2)In the new window that opened go into
  data > data > com.yourcompany.yourappid > databases > You can find your database there.

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm using flash cs6, how can I install this sdk?

Comment: It comes inbuilt with the ADT. In your case it might not be suitable, but have you tried checking general path for sqlite database for applications i.e. //data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<your-database-name>

Comment: yes I've already tried that. But //data/data does not exist in my android device literary the folder doesn't exist. when I run it in desktop I can locate the .db file in AppData but when I publish it and install it in my device I can't locate the .db file